# CakePHP HABTM find first record which has certain related records

Tags: sql, cakephp, has-and-belongs-to-many

I have a HABTM relation between `Games` and `Participants`. I need to find a `Game` which has `Participants` with IDs `1` and `2` "bound" to it. How to achieve this?

I tried with

```
$options['conditions']['participant_id'] = array('1', '2');
$game = $this->GamesParticipant->find('first', $options);
```

Which does not work, because the SQL query ends up with a `WHERE participant_id IN (1, 2)` and this is not what I'm trying to achieve (it finds the first `Game` with either `Participant` `1` or `2` not one which has **both**). Any advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to find games that have both participant #1 and participant #2, I'm thinking you'll need to do a manual join:

```
$this->GamesParticipant->find('first',
 array(
    'conditions' => array('participant_id' => 1),
    'joins' => array(
          array(
              'table' => 'games_participants',
              'type' => 'inner',
              'alias' => 'GamesParticipant2',
              'conditions' => array(
                   'GamesParticipant.game_id = GamesParticipant2.game_id',
                   'GamesParticipant2.participant_id' => 2
              )
          )
     )
 ));
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought of the same solution myself, but was vainly hoping that there was something built in CakePHP for this kind of situation.